# Read and create table from code not from .json file

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am trying to use this [code](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/bootstrap-table.js#L1403) that reads the json from a file. In my code I am creating the json from my database, as you can see below. How can I change the code to read the json from my code and not from the file? In [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/options/pagination-custom-text.html#L24) you can see how the json is being read, in my code you can see how the data is been read to create the table.

```
var columns = ["username", "user_id", "address", "state", "postal_code", "phone", "email"];

var level_classes = {
    "NEW": "new_client",
    "RENEWAL": "renewing_client",
    "CURRENT": "current_client"
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("obtainUsers.php", function(data) {
        var $table = $('<table style="width: 100%;">');
        var $tbody = $('<tbody>');
        $table.append($tbody);
        var $tr = null;

        data.forEach(function(user, index) {
            if (index % 4 === 0) {
                $tr = $('<tr>');
                $tbody.append($tr);
            }
            $td = $('<td class="' + level_classes[user.level] + '">');
            columns.forEach(function(col) {
                $td.append(user[col]);
                $td.append($('<br>'));
            });
            $tr.append($td);
        });
        $('.runninglist').append($table);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".TableWithClass").each(function(){
        var ThisTableHere = $(this);
        $.getJSON($(this).data("url"), function(data) {
            var $table = ThisTableHere;
            .
            .
            Use your other data parameters here
            .
            .
            $('.runninglist').append($table);
    });
});
```

The only difference here is that you WILL have to wait for that page to execute before the client gets the full HTML, in the other one your page will load and do an ajax call

Comment: Did you see how in the original code the data is read from a file in the system, `<table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-height="460"
           data-url="../json/data1.json"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-page-size="5"
           data-page-list="[5,8,10]"
           data-pagination-first-text="First"
           data-pagination-pre-text="Previous"
           data-pagination-next-text="Next"
           data-pagination-last-text="Last">
        <thead>`
**data-url="../json/data1.json"**. How can I make it read the data instead of the file?

Comment: So if you want to do it after the fact, you would need to do a $(document).ready.... and than do a $(".ClassForTable").each(..... and than do a json to $(this).data("url") and use other properties you are setting in the HTML. I'll update the original post with sudo code

Comment: The problem is that the `obtainUsers.php` is not being called and I am not getting the data in ...